# Create-React-App Auto handles GET to routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

On react apps created with create-react-app I can directly GET to any route from the browser... for example if I have a route  I can just GET to website.com/login and I dont get "Cannot GET /login" that naturally should occur.
For example on my react app I send my user to log in using Facebook and after Facebook redirects him back to my website/oauth2/redirect where I process the jwt my server sends.I had created the react app using create-react-app and this seemed to work yet when I removed create react scripts and manually added webpack I get exactly what I expected "Cannot GET /oauth2/redirect".How does create-react-app do it?

Comment: Can you provide an example

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with forwarding all requests to `/index.html`...